# Python parsing json from string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

I need to parse json from a partial string I get back from a web service. I have the following snippet of code which is working fine but is extremely ugly. Is there a better or cleaner way to do this?

```
x = '"1":{"name":"item one","code":"1"},"2":{"name":"item two","code":"2"},"3":{"name":"item three","code":"3"}'
split = x.split('},')
index = 0
for s in split:
    split[index] = '{' + s + '}}'
    index += 1
joined = ','.join(split)
joined = '[' + joined[:-1] + ']'
j = json.loads(joined)
print(j)
```

Here is the result:

```
[{'1': {'name': 'item one', 'code': '1'}},
 {'2': {'name': 'item two', 'code': '2'}},
 {'3': {'name': 'item three', 'code': '3'}}]
```

Comment: Can't you just do `x = json.loads("{" + x + "}")` then do whatever you like with it as a `dict`?

Comment: @JonSG That won't produce the same expected output.

Comment: The first thing I would do is find out if the web service can be changed to return real JSON.

Comment: @Selcuk Yes, that is *not* a complete solution, but I see you were able to use it as the core of your solution which was my intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the inconsistency by hand (add the missing braces) and use `json` module to parse:

```
data = json.loads('{' + x + '}')
```

Then you can convert the parsed data to the desired representation:

```
[{item[0]: item[1]} for item in data.items()]

#[{'1': {'name': 'item one', 'code': '1'}}, 
# {'2': {'name': 'item two', 'code': '2'}}, 
# {'3': {'name': 'item three', 'code': '3'}}]
```

Otherwise, you will end up implementing your own JSON parser, which is not trivial.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following snippet:

```
>>> [dict([t]) for t in json.loads(f"{{{x}}}").items()]
[{'1': {'name': 'item one', 'code': '1'}},
 {'2': {'name': 'item two', 'code': '2'}},
 {'3': {'name': 'item three', 'code': '3'}}]
```